To present (an indictment) to a court "said of" a grand jury
Does "said of a grand jury" refer to the court in "to present (an indictment) to a court said of a grand jury"?
According to this link, "the phrasal verb '(to) say of' is normal and standard. To say something of a person or thing is to say something about that person or thing." I am not sure if I understand that explanation to the fullest ...
Thank you!

'Said of' is part of the dictionary explanation. Like sharp, said of a blade.

Note that at the link provided, the phrase "said of..." is on a separate line and in a different type face. That means it's a comment on the preceding definition, not a part of it.

Collins has messed up that dictionary entry.  In the conversion from paper to online, the usage note has been formatted as an example of use.

What it means is that it is a grand jury that "hands up" or presents an indictment.  That context is where you would use that phrasal verb; you would use it when speaking of the determination made by a grand jury.
You might find something like this under "hands down":

To set a sentence.

said of  the judge in a criminal trial


And you are meant to understand from that comment in italics that the verb is used in a context involving judges in criminal trials:

The judge handed down a ten-year sentence for grand theft.


Thank you for your explanations!
